# Debugging code via input files in visual studio

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, input

I was wondering if there is a way of debugging your code without having to input data to the console every single time you run a program. Let's say I have a .in file with the input data and I would like to use them to run my code.

Is there any way to do so? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: How exactly do you normally pass that data to the application? Through `StdIn`? Through a filename as parameter? Or are you prompting for input and reading it through `Console.Readline`?

Comment: @jessehouwing through stdin (this is a simple console application)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to standard in for the debugging sessions, you can use the standard pipe options to pass in data. By adding the file to the solution and setting it to "content" and "copy always" the file is automatically copied to the output directory, making it easier to "find it".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can specify arguments in your Main() block in your Console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

The above would be the header. Then you could parse those arguments and open a file (with absolute path) in the first parameter:

```
if (args.Length > 0) {
  string fileName = args[0];
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fi);
```

Then assign those to variables after reading the text:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
    {
        string v1 = sr.ReadLine();
        string v2 = sr.ReadLine();
        int v3 = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    }
 }
```

Then operate on those variables. The text file would contain the variable input on each line.

Reference(s) that might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's not about how to read from Standard In, but it's about how to pass data from the debugger.